# QProgressDialog freezes when the main thread is apparently non blocked

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am working on a project that uses a [`QProgressDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html) during a time-consuming computation process. In order to not block the main UI thread, the class that does the computation is moved to a new [`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) and it is synchronized with the main thread using a start and finish signal connected using [`Qt::AutoConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), the default option for [`QObject::connect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect). My problem is that the `QProgressDialog` sometimes freezes as can be seen in the [this](https://www.youtube.com/embed/0jXc2aaLYy8) video (also attached a gif version, but it is not as clear as the video):

[image]

In this animation, you can see how after starting the project, the progress bar gets stuck at `Second check`. And the application stays like this until the mouse enters again the `QProgressDialog`. This only happens eventually, and it is more prone to happen if you move the mouse over other windows. Moreover it never happens at the same stage.

The main part of the software consist of a `StateMachine` that lives in the main thread and inherits `QObject` and interacts with the rest of widgets (in this case the `QProgressDialog`):

**state_machine.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

class StateMachine : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  static StateMachine* open(QThread* worker_thread, QWidget* parent);

signals:

  void finished();
  void datasetOpened();
  void requestCloseDataset();
  void errorMessage(QString text);

  void progressShow();

  void progressHide();

  void progressText(QString text);

  void requestProcess1();
  void requestProcess2();
  void requestProcess3();
  void requestProcess4();
protected slots:

  void process1Done();

  void process2Done();

  void process3Done();

  void process4Done();

protected:
  StateMachine(QThread* worker_thread, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
};
```

**state_machine.cpp**

```
#include "state_machine.h"

#include <QWidget>

#include "progress_dialog.h"
#include "state_machine_worker.h"

StateMachine *StateMachine::open(QThread *worker_thread, QWidget *parent)
{
  return new StateMachine(worker_thread, parent);
}

StateMachine::StateMachine(QThread *worker_thread, QWidget *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  // Connect
  connect(this, &StateMachine::finished, this, &QObject::deleteLater);

  // Create worker
  StateMachineWorker *worker = new StateMachineWorker();
  worker->moveToThread(worker_thread);
  connect(this, &StateMachine::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
  /// Dataset file license
  connect(this, &StateMachine::requestProcess1, worker, &StateMachineWorker::process1);
  connect(worker, &StateMachineWorker::process1Done, this, &StateMachine::process1Done);
  /// Sonar list
  connect(this, &StateMachine::requestProcess2, worker, &StateMachineWorker::process2);
  connect(worker, &StateMachineWorker::process2Done, this, &StateMachine::process2Done);
  /// Sonar limit
  connect(this, &StateMachine::requestProcess3, worker, &StateMachineWorker::process3);
  connect(worker, &StateMachineWorker::process3Done, this, &StateMachine::process3Done);
  /// Dataset initialize
  connect(this, &StateMachine::requestProcess4, worker, &StateMachineWorker::process4);
  connect(worker, &StateMachineWorker::process4Done, this, &StateMachine::process4Done);

  // Create progress
  ProgressDialog *progress = ProgressDialog::create("OpenProject", "", "", 0, 0, parent, Qt::ApplicationModal);
  connect(this, &StateMachine::progressHide, progress, &QWidget::hide);
  connect(this, &StateMachine::progressShow, progress, &QWidget::show);
  connect(this, &StateMachine::finished, progress, &QWidget::hide);
  connect(this, &StateMachine::progressText, progress, &ProgressDialog::setLabelText);
  connect(this, &StateMachine::finished, progress, &QObject::deleteLater);

  // Check dataset file license
  emit progressText("First check");
  emit progressShow();
  emit requestProcess1();
}

void StateMachine::process1Done()
{
  emit progressText("Second check");
  emit requestProcess2();
}

void StateMachine::process2Done()
{
  emit progressText("Third check");
  emit requestProcess3();
}

void StateMachine::process3Done()
{
  emit progressText("Fourth check");
  emit requestProcess4();
}

void StateMachine::process4Done()
{
  emit progressHide();
  emit requestCloseDataset();
  emit datasetOpened();
  emit finished();
}
```

A `StateMachineWorker` that lives in a secondary thread and interacts with the `StateMachine` and does the process that are thread blocking.

**state_machine_worker.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

class StateMachineWorker : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  StateMachineWorker(QObject* parent = nullptr);

signals:

  void process1Done();

  void process2Done();

  void process3Done();

  void process4Done();

public slots:
  void process1();

  void process2();

  void process3();

  void process4();
};
```

**state_machine_worker.cpp**

```
#include "state_machine_worker.h"

#include <thread>

StateMachineWorker::StateMachineWorker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void StateMachineWorker::process1()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  emit process1Done();
}

void StateMachineWorker::process2()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  emit process2Done();
}

void StateMachineWorker::process3()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  emit process3Done();
}

void StateMachineWorker::process4()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
  emit process4Done();
}
```

The entire example can be found [here](https://github.com/apalomer/qt_progress_dialog_freezes). As you can see, the worker is moved to the thread to avoid blocking the main UI thread. However, as it can be seen in the previous video, the GUI becomes unresponsive regardless of the main thread non being blocked (or at least I think it is not blocked).

Do you have any idea on what am I doing wrong? How can I make the progress dialog not freeze?  If I set the `QProgressDialog` to `Qt::NonModal` instead of `Qt::ApplicationModal` the problem disappears, but I want to block the input to the other widgets, so changing that is not an option.

This only happens on Windows and has been tested with Windows 10, MSVC 19.26.28806.0 and Qt Version 5.14.2. In Ubuntu with g++7 and Qt 5.9.5 it does not happen.

PS: I know that `StateMachine` and the `StateMacineWorker` as it coulb be just an object that lives in the secondary thread and interacts directly with the main thread widgets through signals/slots rather than having `StateMachine` live in the main thread and interact with the worker, but this is not the main concern of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was aparently som bug in Qt. Using Qt 5.15.0 in Windows the problem disapeared.